# How can users make payment via in-app purchase and unlock features of an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app which will have certain features locked in the free version.

I want the users to be able to make in-app purchase and unlock those features.

Is there any good tutorial which shows (along with code) how to do that?

Comment: The accepted answer is link-only and may be deleted by the Review Queue. In case that happens, [here is the link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/).

Answer (score 0):

For in-App Purchase you have two options to go through

**1) in-App Purchase via Apple**
See the below links

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

For testing the in App Purchase, see the iTunesConnect_ProgrammingGuide document from Apple.

**2) in-App Purchase via UrbanAirship**

Visit the link http://go.urbanairship.com/, you can also find good sample code that easily help to integrate in-app purchase in your application.

For unlocking functionality, you should set value in NSUserDefaults once you download the product, Depending on value in NSUserDefaults, you can access it and check weather to unlock the feature depending on NSUserDefaults value.